# Transformar coordenadas 3D a posición 2D isométrica

Tags: c++, sfml

Intento renderizar mapas isométricos, mi objetivo final es renderizar escenas que se parezcan a Snake Rattle 'n' Roll:

---

[image]

---

Así que he empezado por renderizar cubos

---

[image]

---

Ahora mismo tengo una colección de vectores 3D cuyos componentes son enteros (`sf::Vector3<std::size_t>`) y calculo la posición del cubo "*a mano*" multiplicando su posición por cuánto debe desplazarse cada cubo en cada eje. Espero que el código sea autoexplicativo:

```
template <auto degrees>
constexpr auto degrees_to_radians_v = degrees * std::numbers::pi_v<decltype(degrees)> / decltype(degrees){180};

constexpr auto radians_60dg = degrees_to_radians_v<60.f>;
constexpr auto radians_180dg = degrees_to_radians_v<180.f>;
constexpr auto radians_300dg = degrees_to_radians_v<300.f>;

const static sf::Vector2f X_axis = {std::sin( radians_60dg), std::cos( radians_60dg)};  //  60º
const static sf::Vector2f Y_axis = {std::sin(radians_180dg), std::cos(radians_180dg)};  // 180º
const static sf::Vector2f Z_axis = {std::sin(radians_300dg), std::cos(radians_300dg)};  // 300º

struct Map : public sf::Drawable
{
    using block_position_t = sf::Vector3<std::size_t>;
    ...
};

sf::Vector2f to_screen_position(const Map::block_position_t &position)
{
    return
    {
        (position.x * X_axis.x)              + (position.z * Z_axis.x),
        (position.x * X_axis.y) - position.y + (position.z * Z_axis.y) // Y axis reversed
    };
}
```

Así que, cada vez que quiero renderizar un cubo en una determinada posición 3D, llamo a `to_screen_position` para saber en qué posición de pantalla se traduce. Me parece que estoy complicando las cosas y que puedo hacer lo mismo con una multiplicación de matrices (que además me permitiría rotar la escena) así que sabiendo que soy un negado en matemáticas me he ido directamente a la [página de la Wikipedia sobre matrices de transformación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) que está muy bien pero no explica las transformaciones que busco.

Si lo estoy entendiendo bien, todas las transformaciones que explica la Wikipedia son de 2D ➡ 2D and 3D ➡ 3D pero lo que necesito es 3D ➡ 2D. ¿Qué tipo de operaciones de matriz debo usar para conseguir mi objetivo?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo ponemos en modo matricial tendríamos la siguiente ecuación

```
            (    )  
( x y z ) * ( ?? ) = ( Ax+Bz  Cx-y+Dz )
            (    )
```

Es decir, dada una matriz de 1x3 necesitamos otra matriz que, al multiplicarla con la primera, nos resulte en una matriz de 1x2. Esto quiere decir que necesitamos una matriz de 3x2, ya que así se cumple que 1x3 * 3x2 = 1x2

```
            ( A B )  
( x y z ) * ( C D ) = ( Ax+Cy+Ez  Bx+Dy+Fz )
            ( E F )
```

Ahora simplemente tendremos que jugar con los valores A-F para obtener el resultado esperado:

```
            ( A  C )   
( x y z ) * ( 0 -1 ) = ( Ax+Bz  Cx-y+Dz )
            ( B  D )
```

Siendo:

```
A = X_axis.x
C = X_axis.y
B = Z_axis.x
D = Z_axis.y
```

Este modelo te permitiría añadir entre medias matrices de 3x3 para hacer rotaciones de cámara u otras transformaciones intermedias:

```
            ( E  F  G )   ( A  C )   
( x y z ) * ( H  I  J ) * ( 0 -1 ) = ( X  Y )
            ( K  L  M )   ( B  D )
```

Answer (score 2):

### Teoría

Tu cubo puede ser tratado en una primera aproximación como "un punto" (sin dimensiones). Por ejemplo, ese punto puede ser el centro del cubo o una de sus esquinas, y es un punto en el espacio 3D y por tanto con tres dimensiones (X, Y ,Z).

Queremos proyectar ese punto sobre una superficie 2D (la pantalla), y por tanto obtener las coordenadas (x,y) de esa proyección. Una vez sepas dónde cae el cubo en la pantalla, puedes pintar el resto del cubo relativamente a ese punto. Eso sirve como aproximación inicial y funciona siempre que tus cubos no estén rotados, sean todos del mismo tamaño, y no se solapen entre sí (el solapamiento puede tratarse de forma sencilla, pero el caso más genérico de objetos 3D arbitrarios requeriría otro enfoque).

La transformación para pasar un punto 3D a una superficie es, de forma general (siendo `*` el producto matricial):

```
coordenadas_de_pantalla = matriz_de_transformacion * coordenadas_del_mundo_3D
```

En este caso, para la proyección isométrica, y siguiendo [esta respuesta en StackOverflow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159434/how-to-convert-3d-coordinates-to-2d-isometric-coordinates/159440#159440), la matriz de transformación sería una de 3 filas y 4 columnas:

[image: matriz]

Donde las columnas de esa matriz son ciertos "números mágicos", específicos para la proyección isométrica, que son los siguientes:

[image: Numeros]

y la última columna (T) tendría en Tx y Ty las coordenadas de pantalla donde quieres que caiga el origen (0,0,0) de coordenadas del mundo 3D. Por ejemplo en el centro de la pantalla.

En los números mágicos anteriores hay un valor especial, `size` que es cuántos pixeles de pantalla quieres que tenga la unidad de medida del mundo 3d. Es decir, si un punto en 3D está en (0,0,0) y otro está en (1, 0, 0), eso sería que están separados en 1 en el mundo 3D. Pues `size` sería cuánto estarían separados en pantalla esos dos puntos. Una especie de factor de zoom o escala.

> **Nota** por cierto que esos  números mágicos (raiz de tres, 1 partido de raiz de 2) salen de los senos y cosenos que estabas usando tú en tu método "manual".

### Código

Voy a poner un pequeño ejemplo en Python que muestra cómo implementar estas ideas. Elijo hacerlo en Python porque es mucho más breve (y porque tirando de numpy ya te da implementadas las operaciones matriciales, que sería más tedioso de escribir en C++). Espero que la respuesta sirva al menos como pseudocódigo si no conoces Python.

```py
import numpy as np

size = 10  # una distancia de 1 en el mundo 3d, se convierte en 10 pixeles en pantalla
screen_size = (800, 600)  # Dimensiones de la pantalla, para calcular su centro

# Componentes (columnas) de la matriz de transformación, es decir, los números
# mágicos a los que me refería en la explicación (`**.5` es una forma de calcular
# la raiz cuadrada, elevando a 1/2)
T_X = size/2 * np.array([ 3**.5, -1,  -1/(2**.5)])
T_Y = size/2 * np.array([-3**.5, -1,  -1/(2**.5)])
T_Z = size/2 * np.array([     0,  2,  -1/(2**.5)])
# Y las coordenadas en pantalla del origen:
T_T = [screen_size[0]/2, screen_size[1]/2, 0]  # En z ponemos 0

transform_matrix = np.array([T_X, T_Y, T_Z, T_T]).transpose()
```

Una vez tenemos inicializada la matriz de transformación, en este ejemplo (es decir para estos valores de tamaño de pantalla y de unidades), la matriz sale:

```py
[[  8.66025404  -8.66025404   0.         400.        ]
 [ -5.          -5.          10.         300.        ]
 [ -3.53553391  -3.53553391  -3.53553391   0.        ]]
```

Ahora ya podemos aplicarla a las coordenadas de un punto, como por ejemplo uno colocado en el mundo 3D en `(10, 20, 5)`. No obstante hay un problema. Debido a que la matriz tiene cuatro columnas, para poder realizar el producto matricial la coordenada 3D debe tener cuatro componentes, por lo que hay que rellenar con un 1 adicional.

```py
# El método .dot hace el producto matricial
resultado = transform_matrix.dot([10, 20, 5, 1])
```

El resultado será un vector de tres componentes (x, y, z) que significan lo siguiente:

- (x,y) son las coordenadas de pantalla donde se proyecta el punto. Es decir, son las coordenadas que te interesan.
- z es la distancia a la pantalla (profundidad). Esta puedes ignorarla, pero también puede serte útil para utilizarla como orden de pintado cuando quieras pintar muchos cubos. Pintandolos en orden decreciente de z te aseguras de que los más próximos, al ser pintados después, tapan a los más lejanos.

### Demo

El siguiente bucle itera por ocho puntos (que representan ocho cubos) situados geométricamente en puntos de una imaginaria rejilla 3D, en los vértices de la rejilla). Para cada punto calcula su proyección 2d y va guardando todas las proyecciones en una lista:

```py
puntos = []
for dx in (-1, 1):
  for dy in (-1, 1):
    for dz in (-1, 1):
      point = np.array([dx, dy, dz])*10
      result = transform_matrix.dot([*point, 1])  # *point desempaqueta las 3 coordenadas, para añadirle el 1
      puntos.append(result)
```

Utilizo ahora la lista de coordenadas 2D para pintar en cada una de ellas un pequeño cubo, usando matplotlib y un lienzo de 800x600 que simula la pantalla:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x=[p[0] for p in puntos], y=[p[1] for p in puntos], marker="h", s=1000)
plt.xlim((0, 800))
plt.ylim((0, 600))
```

Este es el resultado, que permite ver cómo efectivamente cada pequeño cubo está en el vértice de otro cubo mayor imaginario, el cual se ha proyectado isométricamente:

[image: Resultado]